# What's the correct way to apply Thorn Whip pull effect on a mounted target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

The thorn whip cantrip description is:

> You create a long, vine-like whip covered in thorns that lashes out at
>   your command toward a creature in range. Make a melee spell attack
>   against the target. If the attack hits, the creature takes 1d6
>   piercing damage, and if the creature is Large or smaller, you pull the
>   creature up to 10 feet closer to you.

If the cantrip is directed to a target riding a mount and hits, should both mount and rider be pulled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The target is dismounted

There is nothing in the mounted combat rules (PHB 198) that would impose special rules on forcibly moving mounted creatures. The target will be moved away from their mount and thus would cease to be mounted.

At my table I would rule that this would count as dismounting the rider and thus any feature that prevents you from being dismounted (like the Saddle of the Cavalier) would negate the forced movement.

Comment: You think there should be a dex check?

Comment: To stay mounted? No. To not fall on your face when pulled off your horse? Maybe. Features do what they say they do. The spell moves you. Your efforts to counteract it are represented by the attack roll.

Comment: It would seem more logical to me to say that dismount-preventing effects cause the mount to be moved, as long as it's of size Large or smaller. After all, the force doesn't just dissipate when it hits a target attached to something else. But I suspect that's GM ruling territory.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem The force does not dissipate, it is counteracted by another effect. Though it might depend on the situation. For example if you Sovereign Glue the rider to the mount, I would rule they are both moved (maybe the mount rolls to see if it goes prone due to torque?).

Comment: My experience here is the Eldritch Repelling Blast.  People riding horses aren't connected and get pushed off.  People riding dragons tend to be strapped in and so it's not so clear.  People next to riling get a dex check to grab on.